# python: win32com.client.GetActiveObject("iTunes.Application") failing

Tags: python, itunes, win32com

I've been launching itunes with

```
try:
    itapp= win32com.client.Dispatch('iTunes.Application')
except:
    itapp= win32com.client.GetActiveObject('iTunes.Application')
```

Today, whenever I run this, if itunes is already running, it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fix_m4a.py", line 63, in <module>
    change_itunes_path(s,d)
  File "fix_m4a.py", line 45, in change_itunes_path
    itapp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('iTunes.Application')
  File "C:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py"
, line 79, in GetActiveObject
    dispatch = pythoncom.GetActiveObject(resultCLSID)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
```

Works fine if itunes is not running

The only recent change I've made is going from 2.7.5 to 2.7.6.

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the comtypes Python package - it has better support for custom COM objects.

Instead of

```
try:
    itapp= win32com.client.Dispatch('iTunes.Application')
except:
    itapp= win32com.client.GetActiveObject('iTunes.Application')
```

Try this:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetActiveObject
try:
    itapp = CreateObject('iTunes.Application')
except:
    itapp = GetActiveObject('iTunes.Application')
```

comtypes: http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/